# Spring Data Neo4j and Spring Data Auditing

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

In Spring Data project we have a feature called [2.7 Auditing](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.5.0.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html)

Does it work with Spring Data Neo4j 4 ? If no, do we have something similar to this functionality in SDN 4 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, SDN 4 does not support Auditing yet- it is on the roadmap however.